# Strange error in Razor view, in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

When I have this:

```
@using Orchard.Themes.Models
@using Orchard.Themes.Preview
@using Orchard.Themes.Services
@using Orchard.Themes.ViewModels
@{
    Script.Require("OrchardTinyMceDeluxe");
    var pluginsBaseUrl = @Url.Content("~/modules/tinymcedeluxe/scripts/plugins");
    var siteThemeService = WorkContext.Resolve<ISiteThemeService>();
}
```

I get this error:

> Parser Error Message: The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

```
Line 4:  @using Orchard.Themes.Services
Line 5:  @using Orchard.Themes.ViewModels
Line 6:  @{
Line 7:      Script.Require("OrchardTinyMceDeluxe");
Line 8:      var pluginsBaseUrl = @Url.Content("~/modules/tinymcedeluxe/scripts/plugins");
```

But if I break the code up into two separate C# blocks, as shown below, it works fine. Why?

```
@{
    Script.Require("OrchardTinyMceDeluxe");
    var pluginsBaseUrl = @Url.Content("~/modules/tinymcedeluxe/scripts/plugins");
}
@{
    var siteThemeService = WorkContext.Resolve<ISiteThemeService>();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the @ on Url.Content, it's already inside a code block.

What I think is happening is that razor is getting confused by the @ and the semicolon at the end, thus placing the close bracket into the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I totally should have caught that.